# VS2010 set executable data

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, icons, exe

I couldn't find any answers on the net...

In Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express, how do I set the executable data such as exe version, build, icon, etc?

Also, does the Visual studio compiler adds private data to the executable such as IP or mac address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express, how do I set data such as exe version, build

You did not say whether you are using *managed* or *unmanaged* C++.

For *unmanaged* C++ (e.g., MFC), you need to [create a `version.rc` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852568/version-resource-in-dll-not-visible-with-right-click). You may want to use a [resource editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381915/free-resource-editor-for-windows-rc-files) to help you with the .rc file.

For *managed* C++ (i.e., a **CLR** (.NET) C++ project), edit or create the `AssemblyInfo.cpp` file.

Here is a sample `AssemblyInfo.cpp` to start with:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;
using namespace System::Runtime::CompilerServices;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Security::Permissions;

//
// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
//
[assembly:AssemblyTitleAttribute("foo")];
[assembly:AssemblyDescriptionAttribute("")];
[assembly:AssemblyConfigurationAttribute("")];
[assembly:AssemblyCompanyAttribute("Microsoft")];
[assembly:AssemblyProductAttribute("foo")];
[assembly:AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("Copyright (c) Microsoft 2011")];
[assembly:AssemblyTrademarkAttribute("")];
[assembly:AssemblyCultureAttribute("")];

//
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the value or you can default the Revision and Build Numbers
// by using the '*' as shown below:

[assembly:AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.*")];

[assembly:ComVisible(false)];

[assembly:CLSCompliantAttribute(true)];

[assembly:SecurityPermission(SecurityAction::RequestMinimum, UnmanagedCode = true)];
```

> does the Visual studio compiler add private data to the executable such as IP or mac address?

No. Where did you hear that?

Comment: I'm using standart Windows Library, so I need a version.rc right?

Comment: you probably mean win32. yes, `version.rc`.

Comment: Cant find much documentation about version.rc files, but atleast you pointed me in the right direction! Good, detailled answer! Much appreciated

Comment: Did you click on the version.rc link in my answer? Also, I just added another link to a post about resource editors for VS Express users.

Answer (score 0):

The non-Express route is to right-click on the project and choose Properties.  On the Application tab, the Assembly Information button lets you specify version number.  The icon is also specified from the Application tab.

I've not used the Express edition, so I don't know if those features are present.  If so, I expect them to be in the same place.