# adding dialog - Visual c++ Express 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm used to using Visual Studio 6.0 to develop c++ APIs.  I've downloaded and installed Visual c++ 2010 Express and now I find myself in a foreign land!

The first thing I did was make a hello blank windows app.  That worked ok.

Next I thought I'd try looking at the "about" dialog but darned if I can find it.  I also tried to create a new dialog but have no idea how to go about doing so.

So my questions are....

How do I look at the "about" dialog?

How do I add a new dialog?

I see there is a "add resource" if I right click the project directory but is grayed out.

Feeling like an idiot but thankful for any help....

Comment: @sinelaw:  The app generated by 2010 c++ express has an about item under help that sure looks like a dialog.  I suppose it's simply embedded in the rc file.  ISN'T THERE A RESOURCE EDITOR IN C++ EXPRESS?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can determine, there is no resource editor in the c++ express product.

See [Free resource editor for Windows .rc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381915/free-resource-editor-for-windows-rc-files)