# Any tools to preview the resource file .rc2/ rc3 file in visual studio of my MFC project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, mfc, resources, rc

Recently, I'm maintaining the project of my company.

Visual Studio 2015
MFC

The project contains three rc files:

1. athena.rc
2. athena.rc2
3. athena.rc3

The first .rc file includes the other two rc2 & rc3 files.
I'm wondering how to preview the UI layout inside rc2 & rc3?

```
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""Version.rc2""  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources\r\n"
    "#define WR_ENGLISH \r\n"
    "LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US\r\n"
    "#pragma code_page(1252)  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources\r\n"
    "#include ""WAStrings_English.h""\r\n"
    "#include  ""res\\athena.rc2""\r\n"
    "#include  ""res\\athena.rc3""\r\n"
    "#undef WR_ENGLISH\r\n"

    "#define WR_CHINESE_TRADIONAL \r\n"
    "LANGUAGE LANG_CHINESE, SUBLANG_CHINESE_TRADITIONAL\r\n"
    "#pragma code_page(950)   // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources\r\n"
    "#include ""WAStrings_Chinese_T.h""\r\n"
    "#include ""res\\athena.rc2""\r\n"
    "#include ""res\\athena.rc3""\r\n"
```

Comment: Up until now I have had to manually edit my secondary RC files.

Comment: yeah, but that was painful to do this.

Comment: Have you tried the link in the second answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/381915/2287576 Resource Hacker.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Sure but no luck